# iPhone 4 taking blurry pictures

Tags: iphone, camera

pictures taken on my iPhone4 recently became blurry. No software updates were performed, and not water damage exists. Even pictures taken with lots of light show some blur and look foggy.

Anyone else had this problem? - What could be the possible reasons/solutions?

Comment: Could you post an example? Be sure the phone's not moving, even a little bit, when you take the picture - the easiest way is to stand it up along the metal edge.

Comment: I'll post the obvious-but-it-can't-hurt-to-check question: is the lens clean?

Comment: To add to the list: Are you focusing correctly? Are you using the HDR mode? Also, do the shots look blurry on the screen or just after you've taken them?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance some water vapour found its way into the phone / lens assembly?  Were you using it any place where condensation could have occurred inside the phone?  Radical temperate / humidity changes?  I've never seen this, but I guess it could be possible.  I remember folks experiencing this with first generation iPhones.

Are the foggy bits always in the same place in the photo?

Comment: have you had the back plate replaced in the last bit? otherwise its almost always dust or water vapor on the inside of the back case that will cause it.

Answer (score 1):

A thick skin or cover causes the foggy effect with the flash.  You can force the effect by holding several fingers above the flash and lens and take a photo.  Reflecting light from the flash can cause the problem.